# The onLine API isn't working in any browser

Tags: javascript, html

`navigator.onLine` is always returning `true` and the `online` and `offline` events are not firing for this simple piece of code either in Firefox 66.0.1 or Chrome 73 on 64-bit Windows 7.

```
let statusElement = document.getElementById("status");
statusElement.innerText = navigator.onLine ? "online." : "offline.";

function updateStatus(event) {
    statusElement.innerText = `${event.type}.`;
}

window.addEventListener('offline', updateStatus);
window.addEventListener('online', updateStatus);
```

Where the HTML is simple this:

```
<h1>You are <span id = "status"></span></h1>
```

Comment: onLine checks if browser is connected to internet. you tried to disconnect from internet ? and still getting online?

Comment: What are you doing to attempt to trigger the online / offline status of your browser?

Comment: @Quentin: I disconnected myself from the Wifi. I got disconnected alright but the API showed no change in response. Then I switched off the hardware switch on my laptop that represents Wifi and Bluetooth connections and disconnected myself from browsing Wifi connections. No change. Then I switched off my Wifi router No change. No events fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed my machine and the same code works on a different machine perfectly.

I figured the reason it didn't work on the old machine was because I had an IP Address that was always active. It was an IP that was allotted to my machine by Oracle's Virtual-Box. I found this out by running `ipconfig` on my machine and saw that no matter what I did, I always had the Virtual-Box using my Ethernet card.

And since the documentation for this feature says that it will show a status of *online* if the machine is connected to the network, implying to *any* network, i.e. if it has network access of *any* sort.

It is therefore inferred that this method is not terribly reliable if you want to really know if the user has an active Internet connection, though it does work for most of the cases.

Case solved.